# Trying to use SetOptions on Style to set some default plotting options

Tags: formatting, style, text

I want to set some default options for `Style`. I tried this:

```
SetOptions[
  Style, 
  FontFamily -> "Latin modern roman", 
  FontColor -> Black, FontSize -> 36
];
```

in order to set default options in

```
ListPlot[
  dataplotA1, 
  Epilog -> 
    Text[
      Style[
        "Hey There", 
        FontFamily -> "Latin modern roman", 
        FontColor -> Black, FontSize -> 36
      ]
    ]
]
```

However, if I use the code:

```
ListPlot[dataplotA1, Epilog -> Text[Style["Hey There"]]]
```

I do not get the desired font style.

How could I set my desired defaults?

Comment: An even simpler example doesn't work: `SetOptions[Style, FontFamily -> "Courier", FontColor -> Red,  FontSize -> 36]; Text[Style["Hi!"]]` . I had a look at `Attributes[Style]` and it's `{Protected, ReadProtected}` so it should work (not Locked), and indeed the options show up in `Options[Style]` but something else must be clobbering them.

Comment: You can't set option on style like that (as far as I know), since `Style[args]` is simply typeset as `StyleBox[args]`, with the options not being queried anywhere. You could however use something like `BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}`, although that affects things like ticks as well.

Comment: Try: `Epilog -> 
 Text[Style["Hey There", FontFamily -> "Latin modern roman", 
   FontColor -> Black, FontSize -> 36]]`

Comment: you might consider something like: `ClearAll[myStyle];
Options[myStyle] = {FontFamily -> "Latin modern roman", 
   FontColor -> Black, FontSize -> 36};
myStyle[x_, o : OptionsPattern[]] := Style[x, o, Options[myStyle]]` and use as `myStyle["Hey There"]`